# How use usb wifi and bluetooth on my Pi4

Tags: wifi

I've looked at the thread/s about disabling wifi and bluetooth on the Pi4 but I want to go a step further. I'm building a navigation / auto-pilot system for my boat using Pi4 and OpenCPN, together with a recovered LCD panel from an expired laptop, and will be aiming to use wif and / or bluetooth coms for a number of IoT sensors and / or outputs (such as masthead camera and masthead wind, and tiller-pilot). They are all going into a custom built aluminium casing which will kill the wifi and bluetooth stone dead. How should I enable the usb wifi and bluetooth after disabling the onboard ones (or do I even need to)?

Answer (score 1):

I would first play safe and make sure that the on-board devices are disabled by adding:

```
dtoverlay=disable-bt
dtoverlay=disable-wifi
```

to /boot/config.txt

I would then also use

```
Sudo raspi-config
```

to set predictable network names (option 2 then N3 then Yes).  This should keep the USB device the same if you ever need to add a Bluetooth dongle at any point.

If you find the USB WiFi does not work, comment out the  disable-wifi line in config.txt (I am not sure if this impacts the WiFi software stack or hardware only and do not have a spare dongle to try at the moment).

Note entries in config.txt require a reboot to be active and setting the predictable names will prompt for a reboot.